# Switching between a Schengen visa and a residence permit in Germany

Tags: germany, resident-permit, student-visa, schengen, language-course

So the situation is as follows:

- I am from the USA.
- I entered the Schengen Area on August 6, 2017.
- I applied for a German language course that runs from October 16, 2017 through December 12, 2017.
- I am also in the process of applying for my residence permit on the basis of the language learning course.
- I received a letter back from the foreigner's office that a residence permit could be granted to me through December 12 and I have a meeting set up.

My question is the following:

Once my residence permit runs out (on December 12), will I go back on the Schengen visa and can I use the remainder of my 90 days?